# Is it possible to use Overlay Scrollbars in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, overlay-scrollbars

Is it possible to install overlay scrollbars in Lubuntu? I searched for hours, but found nothing.

I'm using Lubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I can't answer your question but I can tell you this: I started off with Ubuntu 12.04 and then installed Xfce 4.10 so that I can log into a Unity session (2D or 3D) or into an Xfce 4.10 session. The overlay scrollbars from Ubuntu 12.04 work beautifully in the Xfce 4.10 session (for the apps that support the overlay scrollbars).

Comment: @vasa1 - you were on the correct thought-train with your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible...

[image]

... at least for GTK apps such as lxterminal, pcmanfm and abiword.

Whether on Lubuntu, Xubuntu or Ubuntu, Chromium/Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Seamonkey are browsers that do not currently support overlay scrollbars. Midori and Web (Epiphany) do. LibreOffice, the office suite, also doesn't support them.

### how-to

Just install the `overlay-scrollbar` package, logout and login

```
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
```

Comment: Do you know if adding overlay scrollbars to a Lubuntu system makes the interface consume more resources?

Comment: in terms of CPU - no.  I've looked at the memory usage ... this doesnt seem to have risen either.  So I guess its "lightweight".